# ChromaDB API deployment does not work with Python LangChain on Windows Machine

Tags: python, langchain, azure-openai, chromadb

I have installed chromaDB via pip using command:
pip install chromadb

LangChain integration with other libraries seem to be working fine.

I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: I see someone has downvoted my question. How do I know what is the issue with my question? I am facing a genuine issue while using Chromadb on windows.

Comment: from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
loader = PyPDFLoader("data/Diabetes.pdf")
documents = loader.load()
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
db = Chroma.from_documents(docs, OpenAIEmbeddings())

This is how I try to use Chroma from vector stores.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after lot of search, I got to know the problem. Currently, chromadb does not support Python 3.11 due to putorch.